# Array that returns 0 if there are no odd values in it

Tags: java, arrays

'The goal of this method is to return the largest odd value in the array. The problems occurs when there are no odd values in the array. I need to return a 0 when there are no odd values but my code is returning 0 for all tests.'

```
static int maxOdd(int[] nums) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        sum += nums[i];
        if(nums[i] % 2 == 1 && nums[i] > max){
            max = nums[i];
    }
        else if(sum % 2 == 0){
            max = 0;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Sun of 2 odd numbers is always even, so you cannot check for even number by `sum % 2 == 0`. Simply exit the loop after checking for odd numbers and setting value of max,if after end of loop, if max is unset, set it to 0 and return it then after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a lot of code for what should be a fairly simple algorithm; I suggest you default `max` to `0` instead of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and use a [`for-each` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html). Something like, `for-each` value `v` in `nums`; **iff** the value is *odd* set `max` to the greatest of the current value of `max` and `v`. Return `max` after comparing all values. Like,

```
static int maxOdd(int[] nums) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int v : nums) {
        if (v % 2 == 1) {
            max = Integer.max(max, v);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Alternatively, if using Java 8+, you could achieve the same result with an `IntStream`, a `filter`ing lambda to get the odd values, and an `OptionalInt.orElse(int)` to set the *default*. Like,

```
static int maxOdd(int[] nums) {
    return IntStream.of(nums).filter(i -> i % 2 == 1).max().orElse(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set intial value of max zero and delete else if statement

```
static int maxOdd(int[] nums) {
    int max = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        sum += nums[i];
        if(nums[i] % 2 == 1 && nums[i] > max){
            max = nums[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```